# GNOME desktop environment on Ubuntu WSL .... Starting Error

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnome

I installed Ubuntu on WSL and I wanted to install GNOME desktop environment. I installed GNOME D.E.  i `put apt install gnome gnome-session` command on command line to install G.D.E . after that I want to start It on Xlunch enter the following command : `DISPLAY=:0 XDG_SESSION_TYPE=x11 gnome-session`.
But it shows following errors :

```
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(gnome-session-check-accelerated:6054): Gtk-WARNING **: 11:04:51.973: cannot open display: :0
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(gnome-session-check-accelerated:6055): Gtk-WARNING **: 11:04:52.234: cannot open display: :0
gnome-session-binary[6044]: WARNING: software acceleration check failed: Child process exited with code 1
gnome-session-binary[6044]: CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....
```

what can i do?

Comment: no one?????????

Answer (score 0):

disable access control in the xserver (xlaunch) - if there is no checkbox then you may need to add the argument "-ac"

DISPLAY should be :0.0